# 64bit vc++ program seems to run under 32bit mode

Tags: c++, win64

I created a 64bit c++ project in Visual Studio 2010 (under Windows 7 64bit);

I thought I was running a 64bit application, and the following code returned *true*:

```
bool is64bit = (sizeof(void*)==8);
```

but if I called the function `IsWow64Process`, it returned *FALSE*...

More weird things:

- calling `LoadLibrary()` to load a dll under `c:\windows\system32\some.dll` works well
- loading a dll under `c:\windows\sysWow64\some.dll` will fail (error code 193: some.dll is not a valid win32 application)

All these failures suggest the application is running under 32bit mode,
but this is against the truth the pointer type is 8-byte length

I am confused, any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> calling LoadLibrary() to load a dll under c:\windows\system32\some.dll works well; loading a dll under c:\windows\sysWow64\some.dll will fail

Everything you say suggests that you are running 64 bit.

In Windows 64bit, the `System32` folder contains the *64 bit versions* of the DLLs, and the `SysWow64` folder contains the *32 bit versions*.  When `IsWow64Process` returns TRUE, it means that you're a 32bit application on a 64bit OS.

This is the opposite of what the names in the folder suggests, which is likely why this seems confusing.  Basically, the `SysWow64` folder is the 32 bit versions for use under [WoW64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64), which is "Windows 32-bit on Windows 64-bit" - basically, you use the WoW64 DLLs *when you run 32bit*, and the normal DLLs when you run 64bit.

Comment: +1 Everything the OP describes is 100% consistent with a 64-bit application on a 64-bit OS.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yeah - people get confused because using WoW64 means you're running 32bit, which is the opposite of what you'd think given the name ;)

Comment: Nice answer. Realizing the difference between WoW64 and system32 gave me some time ago solid headache.

Comment: I like to think of "Wow64" as meaning "Win32 on Win64".  Well, I don't *like* to think of it that way, but it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Press `Ctrl-Shitf-Esc` to run Task Manager application. In the "Processes" tab you'll see `*32` label by the name of every 32-bit process.
It's a one of the simplest ways of checking bitness of a process.